# generate rectangle annotation in the current figure

Tags: matlab

I would like to insert a rectangle into my matlab figure to highlight a specific region:

```
x = [0 1 2 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
y = [0 1 2 4 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];

fh = figure(1);
plot(x,y)
xlim([0 10]);
ylim([0 10]);
```

I can do this by using the annotation function and defining the left bottom width height of the rectangle.

I am wondering, however, can this be done according to the x and y values from the figure in question? For the example shown, for example I would like to draw a rectangle from x = 1.5 y = 1.5 with a height of 3 and a width of two. This is my attempt:

```
% define location of lbwh in terms of x and y values
l = 1.5;
b = 1.5;
w = 2; 
h = 3;

% convert factor of 1
xx = xlim;
l = l./xx(2);
b = b./xx(2);
w = w./xx(2);
h = h./xx(2);

annotation('rectangle','position',[l,b,w,h]);
```

The problem is that the position I'm providing is in terms of the (0,0) position in the plot and not the bottom left hand of the figure window. how can I correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to just create a rectangle from line graphs:

```
plot([l,l,l+w,l+w,l],[b,b+h,b+h,b,b], 'r', 'LineWidth', 2)
```